# ¿Como guardar y cargar un arbol binario en un archivos?

Tags: c++, árboles-binarios

Tengo una duda acerca de como guardar y cargar un archivo a un arból. Como yo tengo entendido un arból se tiene que no se puede guardar solamente recorriendo los dos lados por separado(Izquierdo y Derecho) si no que se tiene que recorrer de una forma especial .  Segun entiendo la forma de guardar esta bien.

```
 template <class T>
void ArbolBinario<T>::Guardar(NodoArbol<T> *p, ofstream &salida)
{
    if(p){

        salida + p->Info;
       Guardar(p->HijoIzq,salida);
       Guardar(p->HijoDer,salida);

    }
    cout<<endl;

}
```

Pero a la hora de cargar es cuando tengo muchas dudas por como se debe hacer.
Implemente esta forma que va discriminando una respuesto para saber hacia donde se deben cargar los nodos, pero esto evidentemente no funciona dado que el programa se detiene al empezar.Tengo la sensacion que es la sobrecarga de operadores la de el problema pero no se me ocurre como solucionarlo ¿Podrian ayudarme?

```
template <class T>
void ArbolBinario<T>::Cargar(NodoArbol<T> *p, ifstream &entrada,ifstream &resp)
{
char res;

        if(!entrada.eof())
            {
            entrada>>p->Info;
         cout<<p->Info;


       if(!entrada.eof())
       {

       resp>>res;

       if(res=='s' || res=='S')
       Cargar(p->HijoIzq,entrada,resp);
       }
       if(!entrada.eof())

       {


       resp>>res;

       if(res=='s' || res=='S')
       Cargar(p->HijoDer,entrada,resp);

       }

    }
}
```

Este es el codigo completo

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<fstream>
#include"71.h"
using namespace std;

template<class T>

class ArbolBinario;

template <class T>

class NodoArbol
{
private:
    T Info;
    NodoArbol<T>*HijoIzq;
    NodoArbol<T>*HijoDer;
public:
    NodoArbol();
    T RegresaInfo();
    void ActualizarInfo(T);
    friend class ArbolBinario<T>;
};

char nomres[]="respuestas.txt";
template<class T >
NodoArbol<T>::NodoArbol()
{

    HijoIzq = NULL;
    HijoDer = NULL;
}
template <class T>

T NodoArbol<T>::RegresaInfo(){

    return Info;

}
template <class T>
void NodoArbol<T>::ActualizarInfo(T Dato){

    Info = Dato;

}
template <class T >
class ArbolBinario{

private:
    NodoArbol<T>*Raiz;
public:
    ArbolBinario();
    NodoArbol<T>*RegresaRaiz();
    void CrearArbol(NodoArbol<T> *);
    void ImprimeIzq(NodoArbol<T> *);
    void Guardar(NodoArbol<T> * ,ofstream &);
    void ImprimeDer(NodoArbol<T> *);
    void Cargar(NodoArbol<T> *, ifstream &,ifstream &);



};
template <class T>
ArbolBinario<T>::ArbolBinario(){

    Raiz = NULL;
}
template <class T >
NodoArbol<T> *ArbolBinario<T>::RegresaRaiz(){

    return Raiz;
}
template <class T >
void ArbolBinario<T>::CrearArbol(NodoArbol<T> *Apunt){

    ofstream salidaRes;
    salidaRes.open(nomres, ios::app);
    char Resp;
    Apunt = new NodoArbol<T>;
    cout<<"\n\nIngrese la informacion a almacenar:";
    cin>>Apunt->Info;
    cout<<"\n\n"<<Apunt->Info<<"¿Tiene hijo izquierdo (S/N)?";
    cin>>Resp;
    salidaRes<<Resp<<endl;
    if(Resp == 's'){

        CrearArbol(Apunt->HijoIzq);
        Apunt->HijoIzq = Raiz;
    }
    cout<<"\n\n"<<Apunt->Info<<"Tiene hijo derecho (S/N)?";
    cin>>Resp;
    salidaRes<<Resp<<endl;
    if(Resp == 's'){

        CrearArbol(Apunt->HijoDer);
        Apunt->HijoDer = Raiz;
    }
    Raiz = Apunt;
    salidaRes.close();
}
template <class T>
void ArbolBinario<T>::ImprimeIzq(NodoArbol<T> *Apunt){

    if(Apunt){


        if(Apunt->HijoIzq){

            cout<<Apunt->HijoIzq->Info;
            ImprimeIzq(Apunt->HijoIzq);
        }
        ImprimeIzq(Apunt->HijoDer);

    }

}
template <class T>
void ArbolBinario<T>::ImprimeDer(NodoArbol<T> *Apunt){
    if(Apunt){
        if(Apunt->HijoDer){


            cout<<Apunt->HijoDer->Info;
            ImprimeDer(Apunt->HijoDer);

        }
        ImprimeDer(Apunt->HijoIzq);



    }

}
template <class T>
void ArbolBinario<T>::Guardar(NodoArbol<T> *p, ofstream &salida)
{
    if(p){

        salida + p->Info;
       Guardar(p->HijoIzq,salida);
       Guardar(p->HijoDer,salida);

    }
    cout<<endl;

}

template <class T>
void ArbolBinario<T>::Cargar(NodoArbol<T> *p, ifstream &entrada,ifstream &resp)
{
char res;

        if(!entrada.eof())
            {
            entrada>>p->Info;
         cout<<p->Info;


       if(!entrada.eof())
       {

       resp>>res;

       if(res=='s' || res=='S')
       Cargar(p->HijoIzq,entrada,resp);
       }
       if(!entrada.eof())

       {


       resp>>res;

       if(res=='s' || res=='S')
       Cargar(p->HijoDer,entrada,resp);

       }

    }
}
void menu(){


    ArbolBinario<Persona> Genealogico;
    Persona Individuo;
    NodoArbol<Persona> *Ap;

    ifstream entrada;
    ifstream resp;

    resp.open(nomres);
    entrada.open("arb_genealogico.txt");


if(entrada)
    Genealogico.Cargar(Genealogico.RegresaRaiz(),entrada,resp);


    bool salir = false;

    int opc;
    while(!salir){
        cout<<"Menu - Arbol genealogico"<<endl;
        cout<<"1.- Crear un arbol"<<endl;
        cout<<"2.- Imprimir ascendientes femeninos"<<endl;
        cout<<"3.- Imprimir ascendientes masculinos"<<endl;
        cout<<"4.- Salir"<<endl;
        cin>>opc;
        switch(opc){
        case 1:
            cout<<"Creando arbol"<<endl;
             Ap = Genealogico.RegresaRaiz();
            Genealogico.CrearArbol(Ap);
            Ap = Genealogico.RegresaRaiz();
        break;
        case 2:
            Individuo = Ap->RegresaInfo();
            cout<<"Los desendientes femeninos son: "<<Individuo;
            Genealogico.ImprimeIzq(Ap);
            break;
        case 3:
            Individuo = Ap->RegresaInfo();
            cout<<"Los desendientes masculinos son: "<<Individuo;
            Genealogico.ImprimeDer(Ap);
            break;
        case 4:
            {


                        remove("arb_genealogico.txt");

            ofstream salida2;
            salida2.open("arb_genealogico.txt", ios::app);
            Genealogico.Guardar(Genealogico.RegresaRaiz(),salida2);
            salida2.close();
            salir = true;
            }
        break;
        default:
            cout<<"Ingrese una opcion valida"<<endl;


        }

    }

   /* cout<<"\n\n\n_____________________________\n\n";
    cout<<"Los ascendientes femeninos de : \n"<<Individuo;
    cout<<"\n\n_____________________________\n";

    Genealogico.ImprimeIzq(Ap);*/

}
int main(){

    menu();

}
```

**Y el header**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
class Persona
{

private:
    int AnioNac,Vive;
    char NomPers[64],LugNac[64];

public:
    Persona();
    Persona( const char[],const char [],int, int);
    char hi,hd;
    friend istream & operator>> (istream &, Persona &);
    friend ostream & operator<< (ostream & ,Persona &);
    friend ostream & operator +(ostream &, Persona &);


};

Persona::Persona(){}
Persona::Persona(const char NomP[],const char LugN[],int ANac,int Vi)
{
    AnioNac = ANac;
    Vive=Vi;
    strcpy(NomPers,NomP);
    strcpy(LugNac,LugN);

}
istream & operator >>(istream & Lee, Persona & ObjPers){
    cout<<"\n\nIngrese nombre de la Persona:";
    Lee>>ObjPers.NomPers;
    cout<<"\n\nIngrese anio de nacimiento:";
    Lee>>ObjPers.AnioNac;
    cout<<"\n\nIngrese lugar de nacimiento:";
    Lee>>ObjPers.LugNac;
    cout<<"\n\n¿Esta viva?:";
    Lee>>ObjPers.Vive;
    return Lee;
}

ostream & operator <<(ostream & Escribe, Persona & ObjPers){
    Escribe<<"\n\nDatos de la Persona\n";
    Escribe<<"\nNombre: "<<ObjPers.NomPers;
    Escribe<<"\nLugar de nacimiento: "<<ObjPers.LugNac;
    Escribe<<"\nAnio de nacimiento: "<<ObjPers.AnioNac;
    if(ObjPers.Vive == 1)
        Escribe<<"\nEsta viva.\n";
    else
        Escribe<<"\nNo esta viva.\n";
    return Escribe;

}
ostream & operator +(ostream &escribe ,Persona &obj ){
    escribe<<obj.NomPers<<" "<<obj.LugNac<<" "<<obj.AnioNac<<" "<<obj.Vive<<endl;
    return escribe;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Como yo tengo entendido un arból se tiene que no se puede guardar solamente recorriendo los dos lados por separado(Izquierdo y Derecho) si no que se tiene que recorrer de una forma especial

Esta afirmación es, en principio, falsa.

Para guardar un objeto (árbol,vector,lista,...) lo que tienes que procurar es que se guarde toda la información necesaria para luego poder reconstruirlo. Cómo recoges esa información y como la guardas es indiferente siempre y cuando seas capaz de reconstruir el objeto en cualquier momento.

> Pero a la hora de cargar es cuando tengo muchas dudas por como se debe hacer

Puedes empezar por hacerlo a lo bruto, esto es: lees un valor y se lo añades al usuario como si fueses un usuario. Si el árbol está balanceado y el número de elementos es especialmente grande entonces puede que encuentres ciertos problemas de rendimiento.

En este caso es cuando empieza a tener sentido pensar acerca de métodos menos costosos para realizar la lectura.

Si el árbol es balanceado lo que interesa es que los nodos se guarden siguiendo un orden concreto y este orden pasa por rellenar el árbol desde las capaz más cercanas a la raiz a las más alejadas (para evitar que el árbol tenga que reordenarse gastando tiempo por el camino). En función de las reglas que determinen el balanceado la secuencia de guardado cambiará.

Ahora bien, dado que cualquier dato ajeno al programa puede ser manipulado manualmente por un usuario (aunque sean datos binarios), no vas a poder evitar la validación de los datos que estás leyendo so pena de crear un árbol inconsistente.

Un ejemplo. Imagina que tienes el siguiente arbol:

```
   A
  / \
 B   C
/\   /\
D E  F G
```

Y decides guardarlo generando la siguiente secuencia:

```
A B C D E F G
```

Preparas la correspondiente rutina para reconstruir el árbol (asumiendo que la secuencia va a ser buena), la pruebas y efectivamente consigues el árbol original.... pero... ¿qué pasa si ahora coge un usuario malicioso (pongamos por ejemplo el profesor) e intercambia un par de nodos?

```
B A C D E F G
```

Si no validas los datos y los insertas sin hacer comprobaciones tu nuevo árbol no será consistente (nota que según el árbol original, `B` es menor que `A`):

```
   B
  / \
 A   C
/\   /\
D E  F G
```

Así pues, la regeneración del árbol tiene que tratar los valores leídos de la misma forma que si fuesen datos aleatorios introducidos por un usuario. Salvo que sea un requisito o te curres un sistema que prácticamente imposibilite que el usuario pueda tocar el fichero sin que tu te enteres y puedas deshacer los cambios o invalidar los datos, la lectura deberá ser tratada igual que las entradas del usuario.

Resumiendo... no tienes que crear una rutina especial para reconstruir el árbol... basta con reutilizar las que ya tienes para que el usuario rellene el árbol. Lo único que tienes que programar es una rutina que entienda el formato del fichero, lo demás ya lo tienes hecho.

Todo esto tiene sus matices. Por supuesto que el formato en el que guardas los datos y la forma en la que recolectas el estado del objeto dependen de cómo sea la estructura del objeto, pero más allá de eso el proceso es bastante mecánico.